# cfhttp Passing POST variables via a link that is clicked?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I was looking at the cfhttp tag and it is possible to use it to pass variables via clicked link?

```
<cfhttp method="Post" url="myurl">
```

I am trying to pass variables on a link click (for example, user IDs), but it seems a bit insecure to send via GET...

Comment: Remember that when using CFHTTP, the HTTP request will be coming from the ColdFusion server, not from the user's browser. That can make a difference.

Comment: There really isn't anything inherently more secure about POST over GET, other than the fact that it is easier to see the variable in a GET request.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by some of these answers, when a simple <a href="#" onClick="document.formName.submit()">my link</a> accomplishes your goal. (Though if it's too sensitive to pass in the URL, it shouldn't be in the form)

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question and am removing my answer (once it is unaccepted)

Comment: It's still not unaccepted, so I completely re-wrote my answer to more accurately answer his question, based off of Billy's answer, and Billy, gave you a +1 for helping provide some clarity/give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer completely missed the mark, but I can't delete an accepted answer, so for the purposes of clarity, I'm changing this answer to agree with Billy's comment above.

CFHTTP is for making a server-side request to another website (as if you were visiting the site yourself), processing the results of that request, and storing them in a variable, which can then be used by you to perform additional tasks against (say, the parsing of a website's homepage for specific values).

What you are asking for appears to be a completely unrelated piece of functionality, in which:

1. You have an HTML anchor (hyperlink) on your page.
2. When a user clicks that link, you wish to pass 1 or more variables to a new page.

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use a hidden form, and have the hyperlink submit then form. This matches Billy's suggestion in the comments for your question:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="pageToSendVarsTo.cfm">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="theuser" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="42" />
</form>

<a href="#" onClick="document.myForm.submit();">the link to click</a>
```

Here, you have an HTML form with two hidden fields, username and id, which do not display on the page as they are hidden (but take note, can still be viewed if the user views the source of your page). Next, "the link to click" visibly appears as a hyperlink to the user. When clicked, JavaScript is used to simulate the firing of the form submission; it essentially behaves as if the form had a submit button and the user clicked that submit button. What that means for this example's form is that both the username and id values are then HTTP POSTed to your 'pageToSendVarsTo.cfm' page, where they are available in the FORM scope to continue processing.

Comment: Thanks for the security tip (I guess that was the other part of my question!)

Comment: In order to get to this code, you'd have to do a GET, which @redconservatory was trying to avoid. Plus you're making 2 calls on the server.

Comment: I misunderstood the question in haste; you're correct--the OP went the wrong route starting with cfhttp in the first place, and this answer of mine is pointing him down the wrong path.

Comment: This method requires adding a lot of markup on your HTML (a new form for each link) and requires changing a lot of existing markup (the HREF value has no meaning, harder to determine where you will go when you click the link).  This is why I suggested building the form dynamically, based on the existing HREF in the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to send the variables back to CF to do the POST, you could also do this with some JavaScript magic.  For example:

```
<a class="postLink" href="foo.cfm?var1=a&var2=b">Click Me</a>
```

Now, say you want to request foo.cfm as a POST, passing var1 and var2 as POST variables (assumes jQuery):

```
<script>
$(function () {
   $(document).on('click', 'a.postLink', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var newForm = $("<form method='POST'></form>");

     if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('?') != -1)
     {
       newForm.attr("method", $(this).attr('href').substring(0, $(this).attr('href').indexOf('?')));
       var post_args = $(this).attr('href').substring($(this).attr('href').indexOf('?')+1, $(this).attr('href').length).split('&');

       for (var i in post_args)
       {
         var keyVal = post_args[i].split('=');
           newForm.append($("<input>", { type: "hidden", name:keyVal[0], value:keyVal[1] }));
       }

     }
     else
     {
       newForm.attr("method", $(this).attr('href'));

     }
     console.log(newForm);
     newForm.submit();
   });
});
</script>
```

This will stop the normal processing of all links tagged with the class "postLink", and instead of going to that page, will construct a new form object with the parameters parsed out of the link URL included as form parameters.  Then it will submit that form using POST to the same base href that the script points at.  Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VGaPH/